# Mouseup and keyup in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am learning javascript and got confused for those events. What is the main difference amongst `click`, `mouseup` and `keyup` in `eventListener`?

For example, when I visit a webpage and intend to submit something, I can click it with left button on the mouse or just press "enter" button on the keyboard. Both could trigger click. Which `eventListener` should I use in different circumstances? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is `click` event triggers only when you press the mouse button on a certain element and release the button while still on the same element. `mousedown` and `mouseup` trigger every time you press or release the mouse button anywhere in the window.

Pressing `enter` on keyboard doesn't trigger a `click`.

IMO it's best practice to use a native submit button and listen to the `submit` event of the `form` element. Let the browser handle submitting natively. If you don't want to do this, it's up to you which events you want to listen to. Usually `click`, `touchend`, and in the case of a login form, perhaps `keyup` of `enter` in the password input.

Answer (score 0):

`keyup` is fired when key is pressed, thechnically the event is fired when the key is realesed [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)

`mouseup` is fired when the mouse (or trackpad) is realesed after it has been pressed (`mousedown`) [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event)

`click` = `mousedown` + `mouseup` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)